# transpose and inverse multiplication

Tags: matrices, inverse

Given:

$$A_{(n,n)} , B_{(n,n)}$$ A and B are invertible, is it possible that :

$$(A^t B^t)^{-1}  A^{-1} B^{-1} = I$$

I guess no, should this be true only if the AB=BA= orthogonal matrix ?

Comment: i can see, using the transpose and inverse properties that : $$A^{t}B^{t}=(BA)^{t}$$ and $$A^{-1}B^{-1}=(AB)^{-1}$$ ... so i should rewrite the previous relation as : $$((BA)^{t})^{-1} (AB)^{-1} = I$$

Answer (score 0):

Certainly it is **possible**.
The condition is equivalent to $I = B A  (B A)^t$, i.e. that $BA$ is an orthogonal matrix.  No need for $BA = AB$, or for $AB$ to be orthogonal.

Comment: Using the matrix properties, is this correct : $$ A^{t}B^{t} = BA^{t} \\ (BA^{t})^{-1} = (BA^{-1})^{t} \\  A^{-1}B^{-1} = BA^{-1} \\ (BA^{-1})^{t} BA^{-1} = I $$